# Is it better to pass an object or pass individual attributes of the object to widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

for example, if we had a shop app and we use a

```
class Product {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;

  Product({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
  });
}
```

and we have a `ProductCard` widget which uses `title` and `price` of the product

so if we have a product object like

```
Product product1 = Product(
  title: 'bike',
  description: 'black mountain bike',
  price: 2000.0,
);
```

So is it better to pass Product object to the widget like this:

```
ProductCard(product: product1)
```

or pass the attributes we need like this:

```
ProductCard(title: product1.title, price: product1.price)
```

Comment: If you want to send entire data of Object then it's definitely better to pass the Object as a whole is better approach and if you want to pass only selective element of object then pass it individually. I doubt if there will be any performance difference in relatively small app though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the object you are passing. In this case, I think it makes more sense to pass the object, as it will get messy if you end up passing lots of individual attributes, and if you were to change the data structure, or the widget at some point, you will likely have to redo it. You are only passing a reference to the object, so it isn't less efficient to just pass the entire object.

If the object contains other objects, and does not have a finite size, like a list or map, I think it makes more sense to pass the attributes directly to the widget.

Comment: What do you recommend for passing lists? Can you give an example of how to pass lists of 1k objects or something like that across widgets?

Comment: I would just pass the list. You aren't actually passing all the elements, just a reference to the list in memory.

Comment: Ah cool thanks for answering appreciate it!